# Connection times using Java Mission Control and Wildfly 8.2

Tags: wildfly, jmx, jmc

I'm starting to move from visualvm to java mission control. I use wildfly 8.2, which doesn't work with JMC out of the box, but have modified the JMC ini to include the required class path as per my answer in the jboss community https://developer.jboss.org/message/955742#955742

I've been able to connect successfully, however the time it takes to connect is ridiculous. Often waiting 1-10 minutes (during which time jmc often becomes unresponsive) when connecting to a local wildfly instance, it's almost instant, the delay happens only when connecting to a remote instance.

Does anyone know what would cause this to be so slow, and if anything can be done to sort it?

Comment: Do you have similar results when connecting with JConsole? What is the ping time to the server you are connecting to?

Comment: Both jconsole and visual vm are connecting almost immediately.

Comment: Do you get the same problem if you try connecting remotely to something more simple than wildfly?

Comment: Which version of JMC are you using? 5.5?

Comment: I suspect this may be due to rather bad ping times, in conjunction with JMC doing a few more roundtrips to fetch metadata. I'll see if I can borrow a server in some remote office and do some profiling.

Comment: @Klara I don't get the same with a simple app. Just put together a jar that did literally nothing, enabled jmx and tried it out on the same remote server, connected within a second or so.

Comment: @Hirt Yes I'm on 5.5

Comment: Any news on this? I am facing the same issue :(